# How to add a repeated element based on button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How to add a repeated element using a button click example code is given bellow I am not able to set proper event that can add multiple div element based on click.

```
   const Form =  document.createElement('form)
   const Input = document.createElement('input')   
   const Button = document.createElement('button')     
   const NewDiv = document.createElement('div').className = "repeatedBlock" 

   NewDiv.append(Input)
   NewDiv.append(Button)
   Form.append(NewDiv)
    
   Button.onclick = function changeContent() {
      // append multiple NewDiv in the Form element based on every click
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, I have created a form, then call a function which creates div and bind event inside it. Let me know if required more details on this.
Change name, provide id to each field. These are up to you.

```js
const Form =  document.createElement('form');
Form.id = "form";  
document.body.appendChild(Form);
     const Button = document.createElement('button') ; 
Button.textContent ="Click";
Button.addEventListener("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); createDiv() });
Form.appendChild(Button);
createDiv();

function createDiv() {
var i = document.getElementById('form');
  const NewDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const Input  = document.createElement('input')   ;

  NewDiv.append(Input);   
i.appendChild(NewDiv);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot,  Your solution worked perfectly. Is there a way we have only one Button instead of multiple copies?

Answer (score 1):

**Only a single Button**

```js
const Form =  document.createElement('form');
const Button = document.createElement('button')  
document.body.appendChild(Form);
Button.innerHTML = "Go";
Button.classList.add("formBtn");
window.onload = generateNew;
Form.appendChild(Button)

var x = 0;
function generateNew(e){
   x++;
   e.preventDefault();
   
   const Input  = document.createElement('input')   
      
   const NewDiv = document.createElement('div')
   NewDiv.classList.add( "repeatedBlock" );
   Input.value = "Input #"+x;

   NewDiv.append(Input);
   Form.append(NewDiv);
   
   setEvents();
}
function setEvents(){
   var Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".formBtn");
   for(i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++){
      Buttons[i].addEventListener("click", generateNew);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect accept I don't want to create multiple buttons.

Comment: @jax Answer Updated